# What is the Prolog operator `^` ("caret")?

Tags: lambda, prolog, exponentiation, iso-prolog, prolog-setof

What is the Prolog operator `^` ?

Looking at [The Prolog Built-in Directive op](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/cs9414/notes/prolog/op.html) gives a list of the built-in operators.

I see

- `**` is *exponentiation*
- `/\` is *or*

but what is `^` ?

Each of the three current answers are of value and I learned something:

- Roy for the book
- false for the examples
- I accepted the answer by CapelliC because it made clear that ^/2 has multiple meanings
  depending on context which instantly cleared up my confusion.

Comment: Please note that the operators you give in above link differ from both the standard and SWI! They are outdated by at least 10 years. As an example, it should be `current_op(200,fy,-).`

Comment: It is actually called the [Caret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Prolog, most symbols can be used 'uninterpreted', at syntactic level, in particular after an `op/3` declaration, any atom can be used as *operator*. Then you can use, for instance, `^/2` as a function constructor for a domain specific language (a DSL), with a semantic specified from your rules.

Is SWI-Prolog (or more generally in ISO Prolog), `current_op/3` gives you information about declared operators:

```
?- current_op(X,Y,^).
X = 200,
Y = xfy.
```

That said, any Prolog implementing `setof/3` is expected to interpret `^/2` as a quantification specifier, when put to decorate the 2<sup>nd</sup> argument. As well, any Prolog implementing `is/2` is expected to interpret `^/2` as exponentiation, when occurring on the right side of the `is/2` expression.

Comment: So the semantic meaning of ^/2 can change within the same Prolog depending on the associated context, e.g. either is/2 or setof/3?

Answer (score 12):

The operator `(^)/2` serves several purposes:

### `setof/3`, `bagof/3`

Here it is used to denote the *existential variables (set) of a term*.  Like in
`setof(Ch, P^child_of(Ch,P), Chs)` where `P` is declared as an existential variable.

As a non-standard side effect to this, many systems have defined it as predicate with the following definition:

```
_^Goal :- Goal
```

But then, others do not have such a definition. It is in any case a good idea to avoid to define a predicate `(^)/2`.

### `(^)/2` - power

This is an evaluable functor accessible via `(is)/2` and arithmetic comparison like `(=:=)/2` and `(>)/2`. Also [`library(clpfd)`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html) uses it with this meaning. In contrast to `(**)/2` which always results in a float, `2^2` is an integer - thereby permitting arithmetics with bigints. Just try `?- X is 7^7^7.` to see if your system supports them.

Finally, there are user defined uses for `(^)/2` that do not collide with above uses like lambda expressions via [`library(lambda)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog+lambda) ([source](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/lambda.pl)).

---

There are a few general remarks about its use. `(^)/2` associates to the right which means that:
`(7^7^7) = (7^(7^7))`. It has a very low priority which means that you have to use brackets for arguments with standard operators.

Answer (score 5):

In math expressions, ^ is exponentiation, it's just different notation for **.

In lambda expressions, it is a parameter-passing operator.

As in Pereira and Shieber's book:

*Thus the lambda expression λ x. x + 1 would be encoded in Prolog as X^(X+1). Similarly, the lambda expression λ x. λ y.wrote(y, x) would be encoded as the Prolog term X^Y^wrote(Y,X), assuming right associativity of "^"*

Comment: http://www.mtome.com/Publications/PNLA/prolog-digital.pdf‎ (digital edition) and http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/shieber/Biblio/ (check out the 1987 entry).

Comment: that's my *preferred* Prolog book!

Comment: _"Thus the lambda expression λ x. x + 1 would be encoded in Prolog as X^(X+1)."_ I don't understand this. It's completely the inverse. `X^foo(X,Y)` actually means do NOT expose `X` in `foo` as parameter to the outside. Prolog by default already exposes `X` and `Y` in `foo(X,Y)` and not really as lambda parameters but as clause-global variables.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer My understandig of the aforementioned book is that the authors use `^` as a term constructor. The terms they construct mirror lambda expressions, to have a way of composing first-order logic propositions from smaller parts (as a FOL "DSL" or encoding, if you will). They interpret `X^foo(X,Y)` to mean _λx.foo(x,y)_. So in _this_ interpretation `X` is the formal parameter of the lambda expression, and `foo(X,Y)` is the body of it. For Prolog these are just terms with logical variables. The semantics are what you define by the predicates that process such terms.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my addition to the use of `^` in `setof/3` and `bagof/3`.

**Upfront note**:

Personally, I consider the semantics of `^` to be a failure, because it *looks* as if this were an "existential quantification" and is even described as such sometimes (for example: [GNU Prolog](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#sec114), [SWI-Prolog library(yall)](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=yall)) but it actually is **NOT**. **Avoid this misfeature**, write a separate predicate to be called by `setof/3` and `bagof/3` instead. An ISO Prolog-2, if it ever happens, should really clean this up.

**We start with an overview ASCII Image:**

```
                                 Clause-wide variable
                                         |
                                         |
                +------------------------+------------------------+
                |                                                 |
                |          Clause-wide variables                  |
                |          that are collected via the             |
                |          template at arg-position 1 by          |
                |          setof/3 (NOT local to setof/3)         |
                |          thus can be constrained elsewhere      |
                |          in the clause (possibly accidentally)  |
                |                           |                     |
                |                           |                     |                
                |                +-+--------+----------+-+        |
                |                | |                   | |        |
                |                | |                   | |        |            
get_closed_set(Set,K) :- setof( [X,Y] , P^R^search(P,R,X,Y,K) , Set).
                   |                    | |        | |     |
                   |                    <-------------------> Goal expression 
                   |                    | |        | |     |
                   |                    | |        | |     |                   
                   +---------------------------------------+-----+                    
                                        | |        | |           |
                                        | |        | |           |
                                        +-+----+---+-+          Clause-wide variable.
                                               |                Backtracking over this
                                               |                is done by the caller
                                               |                of get_closed_set/2.
                                               |
                                       Variables marked as "free for
                                       backtracking if fresh".
                                       This is NEARLY the same as "being
                                       local to the goal expression" or
                                       "being existentially quantified."
                                       Backtracking over these is done by setof/3.
                                       If these appear elsewhere in the clause,
                                       they be constrained (possibly accidentally)!
```

## Test Cases for Expected Behaviour

```
search(1,n,a,g).
search(2,m,a,g).

search(2,m,a,j).
search(1,m,a,j).
search(3,w,a,j).
search(3,v,a,j).

search(2,v,b,g).
search(3,m,b,g).
search(5,m,b,g).

search(2,w,b,h).


% ===
% HATTY EXPRESSIONS ("CLOSED EXPRESSIONS")
% ===

% If P and R do not appear anywhere else than in the goal expression.
% "P^R^" (not quite) closes off variables P,R: they are not (not quite) 
% invisible outside of the goal expression "P^R^search(P,R,X,Y)"

get_closed_set(Set) :- setof( [X,Y] , P^R^search(P,R,X,Y) , Set).
get_closed_bag(Bag) :- bagof( [X,Y] , P^R^search(P,R,X,Y) , Bag).

% The above is the same as this (which I recommend for clarity and
% to avoid annoying bug searches):

indirect_search(X,Y) :- search(_P,_R,X,Y).

get_closed_set_indirect(Set) :- setof( [X,Y] , indirect_search(X,Y) , Set).
get_closed_bag_indirect(Bag) :- bagof( [X,Y] , indirect_search(X,Y) , Bag).

% ===
% NONHATTY EXPRESSIONS ("OPEN EXPRESSIONS")
% ===

get_open_set(Set,P,R) :- setof( [X,Y] , search(P,R,X,Y) , Set).
get_open_bag(Bag,P,R) :- bagof( [X,Y] , search(P,R,X,Y) , Bag).

% ===
% TESTING
% ===

:- begin_tests(hat_operator).

test(clo_set)     :- get_closed_set(Set),
                     format("Closed Set:\n  ~q\n",[Set]),
                     Set = [[a,g],[a,j],[b,g],[b,h]].

test(clo_bag)     :- get_closed_bag(Bag),
                     format("Closed Bag:\n  ~q\n",[Bag]),
                     Bag = [[a,g],[a,g],[a,j],[a,j],[a,j],[a,j],[b,g],[b,g],[b,g],[b,h]].

test(clo_set_ind) :- get_closed_set_indirect(Set),
                     format("Closed Set, indirect:\n  ~q\n",[Set]),
                     Set = [[a,g],[a,j],[b,g],[b,h]].

test(clo_bag_ind) :- get_closed_bag_indirect(Bag),
                     format("Closed Bag, indirect:\n  ~q\n",[Bag]),
                     Bag = [[a,g],[a,g],[a,j],[a,j],[a,j],[a,j],[b,g],[b,g],[b,g],[b,h]].

test(opn_set)     :- bagof(solution(Set,P,R), get_open_set(Set,P,R), OuterBag),
                     format("Bag for get_open_set/3:\n  ~q\n",[OuterBag]).

test(opn_bag)     :- bagof(solution(Bag,P,R), get_open_bag(Bag,P,R), OuterBag),
                     format("Bag for get_open_bag/3:\n  ~q\n",[OuterBag]).

:- end_tests(hat_operator).

rt :- run_tests(hat_operator).
```

When we run `rt`, nothing unexpected occurs, we are like Fonzi with existential quantifiers:

```
Closed Set:            [[a,g],[a,j],[b,g],[b,h]]

Closed Bag:            [[a,g],[a,g],[a,j],[a,j],[a,j],[a,j], 
                        [b,g],[b,g],[b,g],[b,h]]

Closed Set, indirect:  [[a,g],[a,j],[b,g],[b,h]]

Closed Bag, indirect:  [[a,g],[a,g],[a,j],[a,j],[a,j],[a,j],
                        [b,g],[b,g],[b,g],[b,h]]

Bag for get_open_set/3:  [solution([[a,j]],1,m),solution([[a,g]],1,n),
                          solution([[a,g],[a,j]],2,m),solution([[b,g]],2,v),
                          solution([[b,h]],2,w),solution([[b,g]],3,m),
                          solution([[a,j]],3,v),solution([[a,j]],3,w),
                          solution([[b,g]],5,m)]

Bag for get_open_bag/3:  [solution([[a,j]],1,m),solution([[a,g]],1,n),
                          solution([[a,g],[a,j]],2,m),solution([[b,g]],2,v),
                          solution([[b,h]],2,w),solution([[b,g]],3,m),
                          solution([[a,j]],3,v),solution([[a,j]],3,w),
                          solution([[b,g]],5,m)]
```

## Trying out behaviour for less obvious expressions

You may have to run this to see more list output (case of SWI-Prolog):

```
set_prolog_flag(answer_write_options,[max_depth(100)]).
set_prolog_flag(debugger_write_options,[max_depth(100)]).
```

### Singletons in goal expression

If you enter the following, Prolog correctly warns about "singleton variables P,R". Good.

```
get_open_set(Set) :- setof([X,Y],search(P,R,X,Y),Set).
```

### Hats outside of setof/3 or bagof/3

This is accepted and could be given a meaning, but Prolog will be looking for procedure `^/2` on call and say that *"^/2 can only appear as the 2nd argument of setof/3 and bagof/3"*. Okay.

```
get_outerly_closed_set(Set) :- P^R^setof([X,Y],search(P,R,X,Y),Set).
```

A possible meaning for the above might be the utterly mundane:

```
get_outerly_closed_set(Set) :- close_it_off(Set).
close_it_off(Set) :- setof([X,Y],search(_P,X,_R,Y),Set).
```

### Closed-off variable used elsewhere in clause: Problematic!

Now we are getting into "failure of semantics" territory: Prolog does not consider the outside `P` as a variable different from the `P` in `P^`. This is why `P^` does NOT mean *"∃P such that"*:

```
get_closed_set_weird_1(Set,P) :- 
   setof( [X,Y] , P^R^search(P,R,X,Y) , Set),
   format("P=~q\n",[P]).
```

```
?- get_closed_set_weird_1(Set,P).
P=_14996
Set = [[a, g], [a, j], [b, g], [b, h]].

?- get_closed_set_weird_1(Set,1).
P=1
Set = [[a, g], [a, j]].
```

### Variation of closed-off variable used elsewhere in clause: Problematic!

No warnings occur if you write such a thing:

```
get_closed_set_weird_2(Set) :-
   setof( [X,Y,P], P^R^search(P,R,X,Y), Set).
```

```
?- get_closed_set_weird_2(Set).
Set = [[a, g, 1], [a, g, 2], [a, j, 1], [a, j, 2], [a, j, 3], ...
```

In fact, `P^` ends up being ignored. The above is the same as:

```
get_closed_set_weird_2e(Set) :-
   setof( [X,Y,P], R^search(P,R,X,Y), Set).
```

### Free variable over which to range used elsewhere in clause: Problematic!

This is entirely expected behaviour, but a casual reading of `setof([X,Y], ...` would lead one to think that `[X,Y]` are free variables over which `setof/3` ranges. This is not the case: `[X,Y]` is just a template and `X` and `Y` are actually clause-wide variables, which can be constrained elsewhere:

```
get_closed_set_weird_2(Set,X) :- 
   setof( [X,Y], P^R^search(P,R,X,Y) , Set),
   format("X=~q\n",[X]).
```

```
?- get_closed_set_weird_2(Set,X).
X=_20346
Set = [[a, g], [a, j], [b, g], [b, h]].

?- get_closed_set_weird_2(Set,b).
X=b
Set = [[b, g], [b, h]].
```

The above would have been more clear as

```
get_closed_set_weird_2c(Set,V) :- 
   setof( [V,Y], close_it_off(V,Y), Set),
   format("V=~q\n",[V]).
close_it_off(X,Y) :- search(_P,_R,X,Y).
```

```
?- get_closed_set_weird_2c(Set,V).
V=_21682
Set = [[a, g], [a, j], [b, g], [b, h]].
```

but note that this is absolutely not the same as this, where we backtrack over `V` outside of `setof/3`:

```
get_closed_set_weird_2x(Set,V) :- 
   setof( [X,Y], close_it_off(V,X,Y), Set),
   format("V=~q\n",[V]).
close_it_off(V,X,Y) :- V=X,search(_P,_R,X,Y).
```

```
?- get_closed_set_weird_2x(Set,V).
V=a
Set = [[a, g], [a, j]], V = a ;
V=b
Set = [[b, g], [b, h]], V = b.
```

## There should be acceptable notation

One would like to have a clean way of indicating which variables of the goal expression are visible outside of the goal expression, which ones are not, and which ones to range over.

How about this:

- If there is a `λX.` at the head of the goal expression, the `X` is visible outside the goal expression. Any `X` elsewhere in the clause is the same `X`.
- If there is a `∃X.` at the head of the goal expression, the `X` is invisible outside the goal expression. Any `X` elsewhere in the clause is a different `X` (you are then invited to proceed to rename by the editor).
- Any `X` that appears in the goal expression without a preceding `λX.` or a `∃X.` is a **compiler error**.
- You can put anything you want into the template, lambda-ed, or existentialized, or clause-global.
- The called goal ranges over any variables that it sees as fresh: either fresh ones appearing as `λX.` and any variables appearing as `∃X.`

*(Don't complain about the lowercase `x` above; it just looks that way. `λX. ∃X. Xx`)*

Comment: While this is a nice and detailed answer, it appears more that you are trying to answer this question, [Prolog understanding setof/3 with ^ markings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61191765/1243762). I don't know why it was closed, it is not the same as [Prolog: what does ^ do in setof?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61188599/1243762). Since it is not answering the basic question I asked, I am sorry to say I can not give it an up-vote. Perhaps you can use it latter for as an answer to a different question.

Comment: @GuyCoder You are right of course, but at least I know where to find it in case I get confused again. No worries about the vote, I wanted to chase those, I would be harvesting in the JavaScript domain.

Comment: I too use StackOverflow as a kind of notebook because if you put stuff in a blog hardly anyone will read it, but if you post it here, it gets more eyes on it and sometimes gets good feedback. :) Now that SWI-Prolog has the forum with proper HTML and formatting, I use that more to post such things. So for answers like this I would post it at the SWI-Prolog forum then link from here to there.