# Prolog understanding setof/3 with ^ markings

Tags: prolog, prolog-setof

Could someone explain to me what this is doing?

```
(\+ setof((P1,C),P^R^Bag,PS) -> ...
otherwise ->...
```

I have read the documentation of setof; my understanding is that the thrid argument gets unified with the facts.

However, I can't make sense of the code snippet above.

The full snippet is:

```
solve_task_bt(go(Target),Agenda,ClosedSet,F,G,NewPos,RR,BackPath) :-
  Agenda = [Current|Rest],
  Current = [c(F,G,P)|RPath],
  NewAgenda = Rest,
  Bag = search(P,P1,R,C),
  (\+ setof((P1,C),P^R^Bag,PS) -> solve_task_bt(go(Target),Rest,[Current|ClosedSet],F,G,NewPos,RR,BackPath);
    otherwise -> 
    setof((P1,C),P^R^Bag,PS),
    addChildren(PS,RPath,Current,NewAgenda,Target,Result),
    NewClosedSet = [Current|ClosedSet],
    NewestAgenda = Result,
    solve_task_bt(go(Target),NewestAgenda,NewClosedSet,F1,G1,Pos,P|RPath,BackPath)
    ).  % backtrack search
```

Comment: @DavidTonhofer. I posted the full snippet

Comment: @DavidTonhofer I just want to know what that snippet means, in terms of normal programming semantics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Update a bit later**: The below is not quite correct, better go to the parent reference: [What is the Prolog operator ^?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931801/what-is-the-prolog-operator)

So, just focusing on the `setof/3`

```
setof((P1,C),P^R^Bag,PS)
```

Let's replace `Bag` by its syntactic equivalent set a line earlier:

```
setof((P1,C),P^R^search(P,P1,R,C),PS)
```

The description of `setof/3` says that it

- Calls argument 2 as a *goal*;
- Collects the solutions according to argument 1, the *template*;
- Puts the result of the templating into argument 3, the *bag*, leaving out duplicates.

So in this case, `setof/3` will call (give the expression to the Prolog processor to prove) `search(P,P1,R,C)`, and when this succeeds, collect the resulting values `P1`,`C` as a *conjunction* `(P1,C)` (which is really special, why not use a 2-element list?) and put everything into `PS`

Let's just try a runnable example similar to the above, using a list instead of the conjunction and using different names:

```
search(1,a,n,g).
search(2,a,m,g).

search(2,a,m,j).
search(1,a,m,j).
search(3,a,w,j).
search(3,a,v,j).

search(2,b,v,g).
search(3,b,m,g).
search(5,b,m,g).

search(1,b,m,j).
search(1,b,v,j).

search(2,b,w,h).

get_closed(Bag)   :- setof([X,Y],P^R^search(P,X,R,Y),Bag). 
get_open(Bag,P,R) :- setof([X,Y],    search(P,X,R,Y),Bag).
```

Notice that you can write

```
get_closed(Bag) :- setof([X,Y],P^R^search(P,X,R,Y),Bag).
```

without the compiler warning about "singleton variables", whereas

```
get_open(Bag) :- setof([X,Y],search(P,X,R,Y),Bag).
```

will give you a complaint:

```
Singleton variables: [P,R]
```

and there is a reason for that: `P` and `R` are visible at "clause level".  Here we add `P` and `R` to the head, which gives us good printout later.

## Closed solution

The we can do:

```
?- get_closed(Bag).
Bag = [[a, g], [a, j], [b, g], [b, h], [b, j]].
```

`Bag` now contains all possible solutions `[X,Y]` for:

```
search(P,X,P,Y)
```

where we don't care about the values of the *(`P`,`R`)* tuple outside of the inner goal. Values of `P` and `R` are invisible outside the goal called by `setof/3`, backtracking stays "internal".

Alternative solution for `[X,Y]` due to differing *(`P`,`R`)*  are collapsed by `setof/3`. If one was using `bagof/3` instead:

```
?- bagof([X,Y],P^R^search(P,X,R,Y),Bag).
Bag = [[a, g], [a, g], [a, j], [a, j], [a, j], [a, j], [b, g], ....
```

In effect, the query to the Prolog Processor is:

> Construct `Bag`, which is a list of `[X,Y]` such that:
>
> ∀ `[X,Y]`: ∃`P`,∃`R`: `search(P,X,R,Y)` is true.

## Open solution

```
?- get_open(Bag,P,R).
Bag = [[a, j], [b, j]],
P = 1,
R = m ;
Bag = [[a, g]],
P = 1,
R = n ;
Bag = [[b, j]],
P = 1,
R = v ;
Bag = [[a, g], [a, j]],
P = 2,
R = m ;
Bag = [[b, g]],
P = 2,
R = v ;
Bag = [[b, h]],
P = 2,
R = w ;
Bag = [[b, g]],
P = 3,
R = m ;
Bag = [[a, j]],
P = 3,
R = v ;
Bag = [[a, j]],
P = 3,
R = w ;
Bag = [[b, g]],
P = 5,
R = m.
```

In this case, `Bag` contains all solutions for a *fixed*  *(`P`,`R`)* tuple, and Prolog allows you to backtrack over the possible *(`P`,`R`)* at the level of the `setof/3` predicate. Variables `P` and `R` are "visible outside" of `setof/3`.

In effect, the query to the Prolog Processor is:

> Construct `P`,`R` such that:
>
> you can construct `Bag`, which is a list of `[X,Y]` such that
>
> ∀ `[X,Y]`: `search(P,X,R,Y)` is true.

## A problem of notation

This would be clearer if Prolog had had a Lambda operator to indicate where the cross-level attach points (i.e. between metapredicate and predicate) are. Assuming what is in `setof/3` stays in `setof/3` (the opposite attitude of Prolog), one would be able to write:

```
get_closed(Bag) :- setof([X,Y],λX.λY.search(P,X,R,Y),Bag).
```

or

```
get_closed(Bag) :- setof([X,Y],search(P,X,R,Y),Bag).
```

and

```
get_open(Bag)   :- λP.λR.setof([X,Y],search(P,X,R,Y),Bag).
```

## Or one could simply write

```
get_closed(Bag) :- setof([X,Y],search_closed(X,Y),Bag). 

search_closed(X,Y) :- search(_,X,_,Y).
```

which would also make clear what is going as variables are not exported outside of the clause they appear in.

Comment: thanks for the detailed response, this helps. One question though, what's the ^ doing in this context?

Comment: @nz_21 Added more text. I hope I'm explaining this correctly.