# Prolog - sum of list members

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, sum, prolog-setof

I have been trying to find the circumference of a country in Prolog.

I have the finished predicate

```
borders(Country1, Country2, Length)
```

and

```
setof(Item, Condition, Set)
```

which gives a list of all items into the set which fulfill the condition.

To get the circumference I tried doing this:

```
circumference(C, Country) :-
    setof(X, borders(Country,_,X), Set),
    sum_list(Set,C).

sum_list([], 0).
sum_list([H|T], C) :-
   sum_list(T, Rest),
   C is H + Rest.
```

... but the output I'm getting is only the length between two countries in the border predicate.

My test:

```
?– circumference(C,angola).
C = 201 ;
C = 1376 ;
C = 2511 ;
C = 1110.
```

rules:

```
borders(angola,namibia,1376).
borders(angola,congo,201).
borders(angola,zambia,1110).
borders(angola,zaire,2511).
```

Why doesn't `C` become the sum of these numbers?

Comment: Why not `findall/3`? Why don't you also check for `borders(_,Country,X)`?

Comment: i want to find the countries that bordes one specifik country, woulnt that just give me unnecessary values?

Comment: find all fixed the problem, thank u!

Answer (score 2):

I swapped circumference/2 arguments, but you get the idea...

```
circumference(Country,C) :- aggregate(sum(Y),S^borders(Country,S,Y),C).
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem has to do with the variable binding for the other country. At first it looks crazy:

```
?- setof(X, borders(Country,_,X), Set).
Country = angola,
Set = [201] ;
Country = angola,
Set = [1376] ;
Country = angola,
Set = [2511] ;
Country = angola,
Set = [1110].
```

But if you name that variable it becomes clear what's going on:

```
?- setof(X, borders(Country,OtherCountry,X), Set).
Country = angola,
OtherCountry = congo,
Set = [201] ;
Country = angola,
OtherCountry = namibia,
Set = [1376] ;
Country = angola,
OtherCountry = zaire,
Set = [2511] ;
Country = angola,
OtherCountry = zambia,
Set = [1110].
```

It can't group them together because the other country differs, even if you're not interested in the value that binding received. The right solution with `setof/3` is to make `OtherCountry` existentially quantified, which makes it not matter for the purposes of the grouping:

```
?- setof(X, OtherCountry^borders(Country,OtherCountry,X), Set).
Country = angola,
Set = [201, 1110, 1376, 2511].
```

In `setof/3` and `bagof/3`, existential quantification is a way of saying that OtherCountry will take on various values but you're not interested in them for the purposes of the grouping. There are lots of scenarios where `findall/3` will only produce a single result but you may want separate groupings based on some of the other variables in the Goal parameter, so I think it's good to know about this technique even though `findall/3` is probably a more straightforward solution in this case. More discussion can be found [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986751/existential-qualifier-in-prolog-using-setof-bagof).